# How can I transfer ownership of Parachain?

Tags: polkadot, parachain, kusama, paraid

Let's say that team A has successfully won a parachain slot on a relay chain, and they did so with an account hold by a team member (not a multisig). After some time, this team member decides to leave, and therefore they need to transition ownership of their parachain account somehow to a new key.

What would the best way for the possible scenarios be?

1. The former team member is willing to perform some on-chain extrinsic to transfer ownership to a new account.
2. The former team member does not want to do anything.

On top of this, could the [`swap`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/789ef2fe52b8ca6b71128124b94a0f9e128ef823/runtime/common/src/paras_registrar.rs#L262) function between parachains be used? Team A could get a new paraID owned by a new account, and then they could swap leases to the new paraID? What would happen with the previous state of the original parachain?

Answer (score 1):

The parachain account is not owned by anyone. It is only controllable by the parachain through XCM. When the following [pr](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/5451) is implemented, the owner that registered the parachain will have some more rights until it is locked. This would be especially useful at the beginning to fix up potential issues with the deployment or a failed upgrade.